# How to specify a specific folder when generating test case from phpunit --skeleton?

Tags: php, configuration, phpunit

I'm trying to generate TestCase with the phpunit generator.

I'm using the following command:

```
phpunit --skeleton-test "Namespace\Service\ArticleService" ../library/Namespace/Service/ArticleService.php
```

I'd like my tests to go in `/tests/Namespace/Service/ArticleServiceTest.php`

Is it possible to specify such options with PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Open a feature request in the phpunit bug tracker on github.

Answer (score 0):

The newer phpunit-skelgen (1.2.0) allows you to specify the destination file for tests, which may include path references.